# Way to fix outward dent in rim?

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, repair

On a ride today I ran over a water run off too fast and have caused an outward bulging dent in both sides of my rim. The bulge is hardly noticeable to see or touch but I "think" I can feel it when riding. This rim is definitely on the way out as I've dinged it a couple of times now but want to ride it until I can get a new one put in the hub.

I've successfully removed inward dents but want to know if there is a trick to removing outward ones?

I cannot find a flat spot in the rim so hoping bending back to straight May work.

Comment: There is a special tool for this, which a bike shop *might* have.  Or, if you have access to a small machinist's vice, that should work.  (Sounds like you should maybe run a bit higher pressure in your tires.)

Comment: Was running 50 psi before the ride, just a thorn I hadn't noticed and a failed bunny hop!! I think the Morningstar Rim 'Rench only does inward dings.

Comment: If you only "think" you can feel the dent (and it isn't noticeable) it might be easier to just leave it. Like you said, the rims are on the way out.

Comment: The tool I was speaking of is a sort of mini-vice, but I can't find it on the web anywhere.  Wait, here it is: http://www.bicycleresearchtools.com/rs1.gif

Answer (score 2):

Get an adjustable wrench and a small piece of cardboard. Smash the cardboard as flat as you can and fold it over the bead of the rim- this keeps the wrench from gouging the aluminum rim. Adjust the adjustable wrench down as far as you can while still able to slide it over the cardboard that's protecting the rim. Now, very gently torque the dent back straight with the wrench- it won't take much effort.

This will work for small deformations only. If you see any further indication of damage after doing this, such as a crack in the rim, don't ride it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using vice grips and a tree to do this, in that this should an emergency repair only. Every time you bend a piece of metal you weaken it, and these types of dents also stretch the metal making it impossible to get back to the perfect shape.

Comment: And a tree?  What's the tree for?

Comment: @CareyGregory, Fulcrum.

Comment: An adjustable wrench is better than ViceGrips -- the smooth jaws and parallel faces do less damage and offer more control.

Comment: I carry an adjustable wrench in my tool belt, not in my emergency kit. I carry vice grips in my emergency kit, not in my tool belt. the emergency kit is all about just enough tools to get me to either home or work where I have real tools. I normally don't like vice grips, but their weight to versatility ratio is pretty good in that they can be used as a wrench, cutter, or clamp means that one tool weighs less than three better ones, and as for the damage, it just has to get me home.

Comment: I was speaking of this specific case.  The adjustable wrench is a better choice in the "garage environment".